# Custom UIView with nib file in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview

After updating xCode to 9 version, I noticed the following problem:

I have custom UIView with cart, which work fine until update. I use this UIView in top navigation item [image: UIView with class cartBarVIew]

This view consist of button and label. And when pressed button, open another view controller

Then, when I compile app, no action when click button. nothing is happened (no entered to button function).

In View debugger all looks good: user interaction is On end button is on top layer [image]

For test I create UIView in simple viewContoller with the same class name and it work. Button open another view controller.

What could be the problem that it stopped working in navigation item?

Comment: Did you check your `connections inspector`? How about adding a target + action selector programmatically to it?

Comment: Yes. Connection is right. As I say, this work, but in top navigation controller don’t work